# How can I let music autoplay only when play Button triggerd?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to implement an audio bar on my site that randomly chooses the song to play from a list of songs. The music should start but only when the play button was pressed, and when a song is over, automatically play the next song.

The code below works fine except as mentioned earlier, the music plays by itself without the play button being pressed. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

I tried setting `player.autoplay=true;` to `false` but then the next song wont play automatically.

```html
<audio id="audioplayer" controls> <!-- Remove the "Controls" Attribute if you don't want the visual controls -->
</audio>

<script>
    var lastSong = null;
    var selection = null;
    var playlist = ["sounds/0.mp3", "sounds/1.mp3", "sounds/2.mp3"]; // List of Songs
    var player = document.getElementById("audioplayer"); // Get Audio Element
    player.autoplay=true;
    player.addEventListener("ended", selectRandom); // Run function when song ends

    function selectRandom(){
        while(selection == lastSong){ // Repeat until different song is selected
            selection = Math.floor(Math.random() * playlist.length);
        }
        lastSong = selection; // Remember last song
        player.src = playlist[selection]; // Tell HTML the location of the new Song

    }

    selectRandom(); // Select initial song
    player.play(); // Start Song
</script>
```

Comment: move `selectRandom();` to a button click event and remove player.play(); // Start Song

Comment: Can you please provide the code for the button click event, as im still a beginner. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried removing 
    player.play();

Maddin

Comment: Yes. Music still plays by itself at the beginning.

Comment: Replacing player.play(); with player.pause(); can help you if you want to use the internal play button.

Comment: Your Right! This is the sloution i was looking for. So simple. Thank You!

Answer (score -1):

Create a button and add an `onclick` attribute, move `selectRandom()`
 to a buttons `onclick` function like this:

```js
var player = document.getElementById("audioplayer");
var lastSong = null;
var selection = null;
var playlist = ["https://www.soundjay.com/button/sounds/beep-07.mp3", "https://www.soundjay.com/button/sounds/button-2.mp3", "https://www.soundjay.com/button/sounds/button-3.mp3"]; // List of Songs

function start() {
   player.play();
   player.addEventListener("ended", selectRandom);
   
    function selectRandom(){
        while(selection == lastSong){ // Repeat until different song is selected
            selection = Math.floor(Math.random() * playlist.length);
        }
        lastSong = selection; // Remember last song
        player.src = playlist[selection]; // Tell HTML the location of the new Song

    }
    player.autoplay=true;
    selectRandom();
}
```

```html
<audio id="audioplayer" controls ></audio>

<button onclick="start()"> Play </button>
```

Comment: This doesnt work for me it plays only the song that is in the audio tag and in same order.

Comment: Delete the src on audio tag then, I didn't change your code. I editted my answer, try now.

Comment: Great, It works! the only thing is i cant use the controls of the audio bar to start the music (I have to use the play button) and i cant use the play button to stop the music. (I have to use the audiobar pause button)

Comment: I like that i can use the play Button to go through different songs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I like the sloution!!

Comment: For stopping the music, you can create another button. If it solved your problem upvote and marked this answer as correct. Then if you want, post another question for using the controls of the audio bar to start and stop the music. I would be glad to answer to that. But before, make sure there is no correct answer for your question on Stack Overflow. Glad to help :)

Comment: Done it! (Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.)